# bitnami helm chart fails to launch pods,

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

My VM System has a below config, but when i download any bitnami/dokuwiki from bitnami charts or any other and run the deployment, Pods are getting pending or crashloop back. Can some one help in this regard.

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              1
Socket(s):                       4
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           85
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6230R CPU @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:                        7
CPU MHz:                         2095.077
BogoMIPS:                        4190.15
Hypervisor vendor:               VMware
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        4 MiB
L3 cache:                        143 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
```

issue: [image]

I tried applying pv, but still it is not running. I want to run this pods.

Comment: Did you try to describe the pod? Can you share the describe output please.

Comment: @viveksinghggits 

Warning  FailedScheduling  21s (x20 over 19m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Comment: Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s

Comment: Your pod isn't able to connect to storage according to the output you've shared. Check Persistent Volumes and Persistent Volume Claims to get more detail.